# Load semanticdb tags in emacs without revisiting file

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emacs-semantic

[This section of the emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/semantic/SemanticDB.html) states that revisiting a file is the default way to load tags from the semanticdb, but (in the second paragraph) that it's possible to access the tag information without opening that file again. Does it require another program hooking into the API mentioned or are there built-in settings? I thought maybe the search-throttle setting would do it, but doesn't seem to help. If it does require another program, does such an app exist?

For example, if I open foo.cpp and foo.h, I can use semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle to jump back and forth between definition/implementation. When I close emacs, I can investigate the contents of ~/.emacs.d/semanticdb/ and ensure the tags from foo.cpp were saved.

Then, open foo.h in a new emacs session and try to jump to the implementation of a definition. Until I open foo.cpp in a buffer, I'll get the "Could not find suitable implementation" message.

I want it to work right away. If the file isn't opened I think emacs should just load it into a new buffer and take me there!